# Converting only the first level of object tree using Jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is it possible to make ObjectMapper convert only the actual object without converting the rest of the object tree recursively ?

So that :

```
Map<String,Object> props = new ObjectMapper().convertValue(obj, Map.class);
```

results in a map of [field, value] where values are the actual references to instances of the fields of obj instead of Maps ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature right now with Jackson. You can probably achieve this with a custom Serializer/Deserializer pair that could share some data and "protocol". But, why bother doing this when the easier (and a LOT faster) way would be to have a generic way to go from POJO to Map, probably using reflection.

Comment: Using reflection it is at least an 8 liner, even if I use spring BeanWrapper... I'm just wondering why there is no Utils like method in spring for that...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you are really trying to do here.

But one thing that may help is to keep in mind that `java.lang.Object` type (as well as `JsonNode`) can be freely included in the structure, to get sort of "untyped" binding deeper in the structure. With these types, you can avoid rigid data-binding for some subsets of the object model; and possibly convert to POJOs using `ObjectMapper.convertValue()` more dynamically.

Comment: I was trying to use ObjectMapper instead of BeanWrapper to convert object to Map of key as field/getter name (bean convention) and value as return value of getters. There is nothing related to JSON here. I just wanted to do it more quickly (lines of code) than with BeanWrapper.

Comment: Ah ok. So no, `ObjectMapper.convertValue()` does not have option to only do shallow conversion.